# Trouble returning values in python from functions

Tags: python, function

My below code spits out TRUE although there are no duplicates. Unfortunately I am under a constraint that does not allow me to change the main function. Can anyone assist me in understanding how to ensure I get my function to return back to the main? I'm having this problem elsewhere, so the reasoning behind the answer would be greatly appreciated.

`ONE_TEN =[12, 20, 10, 14, 54, 16, 75, 38, 79, 103] #this is test run 2`

````
#j.   Demonstrate testing if the list contains duplicates.
    print("The list has duplicates: ", hasDuplicate(ONE_TEN))

def hasDuplicate(data:list)->bool:
    '''Return true if the list contains duplicate elements 
    (which need not be adjacent)'''
    unique = set(data)
    unique = list(unique)
    fact = unique != data
    return(fact)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() ```
````

Comment: how about `print("Duplicates:?",False if (len(ONE_TEN) - len(set(ONE_TEN))) == 0 else True)  `

Answer (score 1):

You didn't do the correct comparison.  Trivial debugging shows the problem: simply print the two lists:

```
unique = set(data)
unique = list(unique)
print(unique, '\n', data)
```

Output:

```
[38, 103, 10, 75, 12, 14, 79, 16, 20, 54]
[12, 20, 10, 14, 54, 16, 75, 38, 79, 103]
```

Instead, compare the lengths: your whole function can be simply

```
return len(data) != len(set(data))
```

---

A set is a collection of elements; Python will store the elements in whatever order it finds convenient.  Thus, when you convert a list to a set, the order will likely change.  The definition of a set has no order -- but Python does define an iterator, so you can loop through the elements.

When you make a list from a set, you get whatever order Python likes to use, often some apparently meaningless arrangement that results from the hash function used.  When you create a list from a set, Python simply iterates through the set, so you get that set-based order in your list.  There is no reason to expect this order to relate to anything about where the elements came from.

Comment: Thank you! but now I don't know why the first list isn't the same order as the second list. Also, I still don't understand why the ```fact``` doesn't return to the called function ```hasDuplicate(ONE_TEN)```

Comment: Ahhh understood. But how then do I resolve my code to get the function to return values properly?

Comment: Return *what* values?  According to your question, the function returns a Boolean indicating whether there are any duplicates.

Comment: Return the Boolean so when called it outputs False or True and the variable returned aka ```fact``` can be called outside of the function

Comment: (1) fact is a Boolean; (2) you can't "call" a variable; what do you intend?

Comment: for the print statement at the top to print out: ```The list has duplicates: False```

Comment: That's what I gave you.

Comment: Then I am an idiot and I thank you for your time